# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-12-04T16:00:00.432597+02:00

Tags: kotlin, dataformat

```
class DateUtil {

    companion object {
        const val DATE_TIME_XML_FORMAT  = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
   
 fun stringToLocalDateTime(dateTimeAsString : String, dateTimeFormat : String) : LocalDateTime {
            return LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeAsString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimeFormat))
        }
}
```

But I get error when try to parse text "**2020-12-04T16:00:00.432597+02:00**"

```
15:39:16.858 [qtp192428201-24] INFO com.myproject- importOrder: availableUntil = "2020-12-04T16:00:00.432597+02:00"
15:39:16.863 [qtp192428201-24] WARN io.javalin.Javalin - Uncaught exception
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-12-04T16:00:00.432597+02:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2049)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at .DateUtil$Companion.stringToLocalDateTime(DateUtil.kt:30)
```

Answer (score 2):

For this exact input `2020-12-04T16:00:00.432597+02:00` you should use following pattern

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX
```

Comment: The above or `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSz"`

Comment: @MadhuBhat this help me:  DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME